# The calculation for heat transfer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

When I attempt on the problem below,
[image]

In my workings, I found out that,

[image]

However, when I tried to approach the questions with

[image]

And I get a totally different answer. Which part of my calculation is wrong about the value of heat transferred?

Source
Q5.36, Fundamentals of Thermodynamics 8th Ed - Sonntag-Borgnakke-Van Wylen

Comment: I note that the problem statement is ambiguous.  The vapor pressure of pure water at 300 deg C is 8700 kPa (see https://www.omnicalculator.com/chemistry/vapour-pressure-of-water), so something in the problem statement is either incomplete or in error.  Since steam tables are based on pure water, your saturation temperature at 1200 kPa is questionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your first calculation, and it is correct.  However, there is no work done.  It is all heat removed.

Your second approach is, of course, incorrect because there is a phase change.

Comment: In the first calculation, shouldn't the OP be using the change in enthalpy instead of change in internal energy?

Comment: @BobD The problem statement indicates "A rigid container..."  So no work is done.

Comment: I realize no work is done (boundary or flow work) and per the first law $Q=\Delta U$, but what then is the physical significance of the change in enthalpy in this example, in which $\Delta H=Q+V\Delta p$, in particular, the physical significance of the $V\Delta p$ term?

Comment: @BobD As far as I’m concerned, it has no physical significance to this problem.